# Can't find Microsoft Translator's categories

Tags: language-translation, microsoft-translator

I've been using Microsoft Translator's HTTP API for translating texts in my website.

As [the documentation describes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512421.aspx), there is an option of specifying a category for the translation. The list of available categories is nowhere to be found.

Any help finding it would be highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 9):

I know that this question was posted ~9 months ago, but maybe other developers might find this useful. I have searched A LOT for this answer, because I have to use it myself. :)

All the possible categories are here:

```
Agriculture
Animals
Arts &amp; Entertainment
Automotive
Beauty
Business
Chemicals
Clothing
Custom
Education
Electronics
Energy, Water and Utilities
Financials
Fine Arts
Food
Geography, Anthropology
Government
Healthcare
History
Home &amp; Garden
Internet
Language
Law
Literature
Medicine
Military Science
Music
Philosophy
Political Science
Reference
Religion
Science
Shopping
Social Sciences
Society &amp; Culture
Sports
Technology
Telecommunications
Tools &amp; Hardware
Transportation
Travel
```

I found them by creating a online hub project.
https://hub.microsofttranslator.com/Projects/Create

Comment: Is it possible that these categories are now deprecated? Because none of them works. 'genera'l & 'tech' are the ones that I found.