# Category IDs for Microsoft Translator

Tags: categories, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

Are there other category IDs for Microsoft Translator besides tech, speech and generalnn? Where can I find them?

Comment: BTW, the answer shown at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652272/cant-find-microsoft-translators-categories does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Valid category values are <blank> or "general", "tech", "speech", "generalnn" or a custom category identifier you copied from the [Hub](https://hub.microsofttranslator.com) overview page. 
The result is not necessarily different for every language pair.