# Azure Cognitive Service Text API TranslateArray Category Usage

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

Is the "Category" attribute in a request to TranslateArray a pre-defined list or open to specify during the request?

```
 <TranslateArrayRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AppId xsi:nil="true" />
  <From>en</From>
  <Options>
    <Category xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2">pets</Category>
    <State>0</State>
  </Options>
  <Texts>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">dog</string>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">cat</string>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">fish</string>
  </Texts>
  <To>fr</To>
</TranslateArrayRequest>
```

Yields the following response:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Argument Exception</h1>
        <p>Method: TranslateArray()</p>
        <p>Parameter: category</p>
        <p>Message: Invalid category&#xD;
Parameter name: category</p>
        <code></code>
        <p>message id=0243.V2_Rest.TranslateArray.148495FA</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Definition in API documentation:

> Category: A string containing the category (domain) of the
>   translation. Defaults to general

but it is unclear what other categories there are if this is not a custom field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630374/category-ids-for-microsoft-translator

Comment: This is a duplicate as reference by @MariaInesParnisari, here is the list:Agriculture
Animals
Arts &amp; Entertainment
Automotive
Beauty
Business
Chemicals
Clothing
Custom
Education
Electronics
Energy, Water and Utilities
Financials
Fine Arts
Food
Geography, Anthropology
Government
Healthcare
History
Home &amp; Garden
Internet
Language
Law
Literature
Medicine
Military Science
Music
Philosophy
Political Science
Reference
Religion
Science
Shopping
Social Sciences
Society &amp; Culture
Sports
Technology
Telecommunications

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate but reposting response from one in comments incase search shows up for someone:

Agriculture
Animals
Arts & Entertainment
Automotive
Beauty
Business
Chemicals
Clothing
Custom
Education
Electronics
Energy, Water and Utilities
Financials
Fine Arts
Food
Geography, Anthropology
Government
Healthcare
History
Home & Garden
Internet
Language
Law
Literature
Medicine
Military Science
Music
Philosophy
Political Science
Reference
Religion
Science
Shopping
Social Sciences
Society & Culture
Sports
Technology
Telecommunications